# JSON Object Holding a JSON Array?

Tags: arrays, json, object

Can a JSON object hold a JSON array as is shown in the following code?

```
courseJSONObject.put( "students", studentJSONArray );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like this:

```
{
    "students": []
}
```

For example, here's an object with a `students` array containing the entries 1, 2, and 3:

```
{
    "students": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

More in [the documentation](http://json.org) and [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159).

Comment: One more question.  So then could that object take on data in addition to that array.  For example could the object contain an array of students AND the name of the course as is shown below: courseJSONObject.put( "students", studentJSONArray ); courseJSONObject.put( "course name", course.getName() );

Comment: @Daron: Yes, of course, again please see the documentation and RFC. Objects can have any number of properties. The one above just has one property, but it could have others.